# The element expected „,”.ts(1005) in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

```
// state
//  score
//  player pick
//  ai pick

const playerWinsLSKey = "playerWins";
const AIWinsLSKey = "AIWins";

let state = {
   playerWins: localStorage.getItem(playerWinsLSKey) // 0,
   AIWins: localStorage.getItem(AIWinsLSKey) // 0,
   playerPick: null,
   AIPick: null,
};

const renderScore = () =\> {
   const pointsElement = document.querySeLector(".points");
   pointsElement.innerText = state.playerWins - state.AIWins;
};

const bindPickEvents = () =\> {
   document.querySelectorAll(".options button").forEach((button) =\> {
      button.addEventListener("click", (e) =\> {
          console.log(e);
});
});
};

const pick = () =\> {

}

const init = () =\> {};

init ();
```

As an error the constants are highlighted *AIWins* and *playerPick*

I tried to find an error in the code, but there is none.
Also tried typing in the cmd commands:

`npm install -g typescript@latest`

And returned:

> 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,                                                          operable program or batch file.

**I'm on Windows 11**

Comment: ps. im noob guys, don't kill for my lack of competence

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you commented out the commas:

> // 0,

put the "," before the //

Comment: thx men, i feel stupid for not noticing such a trivial error, but still ty